# Looping Sound Has Clicking Noise At The End Of The Loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have the music looped and everything is working as it should, but for some reason the looping background music has a clicking noise and a stutter at the end of the loop. Has anyone else had this issue and if so how did you rectify the situation?

I used Logic Studio 8 for the sound file with no open mics, So I know it's not the sound file.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/theeye3.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looping it in an audio editor to make sure that the problem is not with the sample itself? If the sample doesn't start and end on a zero point you may get clicks.

Comment: Yes...I'm sure. Just fixed it. What I did was load a second shorter sound file of the same music and it covers the popping perfectly. Both pops from each sound file are covered by the other. I use Logic Studio 8 and the loop was created with synths, quantized....it's not the loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is usually because your sound file is compressed, and thereby not having the ending point amplitudes at the exact same level. I have the same problem in a game, my solution was to add a sound effect (which is parts of the looping menu music anyway) to play 0.3 secs before the looping. It actually covers the problem.